# How to print a value obtained from a form in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I am trying to create a form which asks user to input a value, do some calculations on it and show the results back to the user.
Here is what I've done:
I have created an app called QMarcum.  Inside this app I have this views.py, forms.py and urls.py:

*views.py*

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from scipy.integrate import quad
import scipy, numpy, math
from scipy import integrate
from django.http import HttpResponse
from .forms import Calculate

def integrand(x):
    Q_y = (1/(math.sqrt(2*math.pi)))*math.exp((-x**2)/2)
    return Q_y
    y = Calculate.y
    ans, err = quad(integrand, float(y), math.inf)
    print(ans)
    return render(request, 'test.html', {'form': Q_y})
```

*forms.py*

```
from django import forms

class Calculate(forms.Form):
    y = forms.FloatField()
```

*urls.py*

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('form', views.integrand),
]
```

*form.html*

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form }}
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

The form asks user to input a value (`y`) (`y` is printed on terminal successfully), however, `print(ans)` doesn't print the value AND also I don't know how to show the calculated result (`ans`) to user.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It looks like there is no action in the form

Comment: You haven't done any of the things you need to do when using a form: instantiating it, passing in the submitted data, checking if it is valid, and getting the validated data back from cleaned_data. Did you read the documentation?

Comment: @DanielRoseman can you please come here :https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106/r I have one question regarding Django orm

Comment: @DanielRoseman I tried to write the summarized version. My concern is to know if it's possible to receive data from user, do some mathematic calculations using other python packages,, and return back the result to the user immediately after he pressed submit button.

Comment: @DanielRosemanin fact there are lots of websites doing this such as online calculators, but most of them are using php or JS. Is it possible to perform it in Django, too? I don't want to redirect the user to another page to show him the result, I want him to see tge result right after he pressed submit button in the same page below the form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In views.py what is quad it is causing many errors, i don't know that function.

```
from django.shortcuts import render,HttpResponse
from scipy.integrate import quad
import scipy, numpy, math
from scipy import integrate
from django.http import HttpResponse
from .forms import Calculate
from django.shortcuts import render


from django.http import HttpResponse
from .forms import Calculate

def integrand(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':       # accept the information
        form = Calculate(request.POST) # "populate" a form with that data
        print(form.data["y"])
        y=int(form.data["y"])
        # print the value of y
        Q_y = (1 / (math.sqrt(2 * math.pi))) * math.exp((-y ** 2) / 2)
        y = Q_y
        #ans = quad(integrand, float(y), math.inf)
        print(Q_y)

        return HttpResponse(str(Q_y))
    else: # show the form to the user
        return render(request, 'forms.html', {'form': Calculate()})
```

Comment: thanks for your reply. Consider it as a simple online calculator. The user enters a digit and wants to double it. Once he enters a value and pressed the submit button, I want to do the math calculation in back end and immediately show him the result in the same page below submit button. How can I handle it ib Django? thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have several problems in your implementation.

First, any view's first argument is always `request`. This objects let's you access many different variables regarding the request made by the user's browser.

In this case, you want to "populate" your form with the data received from the user, but you also want to display the page so that the user sees the form.

What you want to do is return the html if the user is accessing the page, and accept the information if the user has submitted the form.

For this, you'll want to separate the logic between different HTTP methods:

- GET returns the HTML
- POST accepts the information

```py
from django.http import HttpResponse
from .forms import Calculate

def integrand(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':       # accept the information
        form = Calculate(request.POST) # "populate" a form with that data
        print(form.data["y"])          # print the value of y
        # add additional logic with the data here
        return HttpResponse("Thank you for submitting!")
    else: # show the form to the user
        return render(request, 'test.html', {'form': Calculate()})
```

Comment: thanks for your reply. Consider it as a simple online calculator. The user enters a digit and wants to double it. Once he enters a value and pressed the submit button, I want to do the math calculation in back end and immediately show him the result in the same page below submit button. How can I handle it ib Django? thanks